# When do I need to add a hash to my own object, for example a python data class?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, key

I find myself in one of two situations very often. I have a class, either a standard class

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

or a dataclasss

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class myClass:
    x: float
```

Now, all I want is to be able to store these two classes as keys in a dictionary, such that the hash is on the instant of the object itself, so look-up will work if (and only if) I look-up using the exact same instant of the object that I stored as key.

I've read online a bit, and what confuses me is the `__eq__` operator. I have no idea why that is relevant here. All I want is for dictionaries to remember the object by its id. So, my questions are

1. do I need to add `def __hash__(self): return id(self)` to any of those two objects above, or is this always implicit?
2. do I need to add `__eq__`?

Comment: Every object inherits from `object` which has a default implementation of `__hash__` and `__eq__`. That default implementation uses the id of the instance if your class does not implement the `__eq__`. If it does implement the `__eq__` then the `__hash__` is set to `None` and it is left for you to implement if you want/need to.